# nvidia-driver-418 stopped working after ubuntu 22.04 update to kernel 5.19

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

I'm using my 10 years old laptop as an engineering machine for 3d printing and CAD with ubuntu 22.04 and it has one of those mobile kepler GPUs with 418 being the latest available driver. It even has some vulkan support so things were pretty good until recent kernel update to 5.19 after which I could not get past booting screen with this driver. I performed a safe mode boot, removed the 418 driver and booted normally.

I also tried few other available drivers, 390 and nouveau drivers do work, but 418 was performing way better. Is there any chance to make it work again?

Comment: Why remove the driver, go back to older kernel.

Comment: @David that's what I did today - rolled back to kernel 5.15, but is it sustainable? Won't future ubuntu updates just break it again and again?

Comment: Maybe but if it was me I would allow a new kernel to load and see if the issue is gone. If not load the one you know works again. BTW you never said what kernel you used for example here is a full kernel number 5.4.0-144-generic. You only gave part of the kernel info.

Comment: @David linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic to be specific, sorry I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: NP My point was a later one like strictly an example 5.19.0-58-generic May work.